# Laravel - Error ResetPasswordController not found in route list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-controller

I have this error while execute the command `php artisan route:list` :

```
ReflectionException  : Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController does not exist

at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:790
```

Where can I check? I use the `php artisan make:auth` to generate this file.
The file exists under app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php.

This is the content:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

    class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Password Reset Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
        | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
        | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
        |
        */

        use ResetsPasswords;

        /**
        * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
        *
        * @var string
        */
        protected $redirectTo = '/home';

        /**
        * Create a new controller instance.
        *
        * @return void
        */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest');
        }
    }
```

Comment: run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Thanks, it resolve !!!

Comment: Glad it helped, I made my comment an answer with explanation if you're willing to accept it for potential new visitors, thanks

Comment: See if this is related, after updating to 6.2 / 6.3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58338457/after-update-laravel-6-2-app-http-controllers-auth-confirmpasswordcontroller-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes are cached and don't get a fresh version of your files/classes

So you need to add them to the classmap by running

```sh
composer dumpautoload
```

Hope this helps