# after Update laravel 6.2 [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

I update laravel from v 6.0 to v6.2 and after the finish, I try `php artisan route:list`

This error

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue, i fixed it with the following solution:

1. Create a empty file named "ConfirmPasswordController.php" in the folder App/Http/Controllers/Auth
2. Go to https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth en open the file named "ConfirmPasswordController.php"
3. Copy all the file contents to your newly created file and save it.

This should fix the error.

**Edit**
The problem is, were updating the composer dependencies, but not the core application. But de composer dependencies expect you to update the core. They refer to files on the core application that not exists (because the application is not up-to-date).

See: [How to update Laravel Application (not the composer dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374153/how-to-update-laravel-application-not-the-composer-dependencies)

Comment: Yeap, this hack is the actually solution, I hope they fix it.

Comment: @Kvlknctk: there are more: see [https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases)

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed. Just update to Laravel 6.4

Answer (score 2):

**Step1.** Create **ConfirmPasswordController.php** file in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/` path.

**Step2.** [ConfirmPasswordController.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ConfirmPasswordController.php) paste this content to `ConfirmPasswordController.php` file.

From v6.0.0 to v6.2.0 the following addition and modifications were made.

> Added app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ConfirmPasswordController.php
>
> Modified app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ForgotPasswordController.php
>
> Modified app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php
>
> Modified app/Http/Kernel.php
>
> Modified config/auth.php
>
> Modified resources/lang/en/validation.php

You can see the diff of v6.0.0 to v6.2.0 [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/compare/v6.0.0...v6.2.0#files_bucket).

Comment: A app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ConfirmPasswordController.php this file missing

Comment: if I need to update v6.0 to v6.2.How should I update it? , so now I just change "laravel/framework": "^6.2", in composer.json and run command composer update

Answer (score 0):

Create `ConfirmPasswordController.php` manually and It's may be duplicate of - [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310002/confirmpasswordcontroller-doesnt-exist-after-upgrade-from-laravel-5-8-to-6-2)

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Open file  vender/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php".

2 ) and comment these

```
    // $this->get('password/confirm', 'Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm')->name('password.confirm');
    // $this->post('password/confirm', 'Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm');
```

Comment: You should avoid making changes directly to the vendor folder as it will be overwritten in future updates.